# How to query a file path from MySQL table and get it to display as a link

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to figure out how to query several columns of data into a table on my webpage using PHP and get one column to display as clickable audio files. In my MySQL table the audio column consists of absolute paths to audio files saved in a folder on the disk of my web host. All attempts so far have only succeeded in querying the file path as text, not as clickable audio.

I've been using a PHP loop statement to try to query several data columns into a table, like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, word, audio FROM dictionary";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["word"]. " " . $row["audio"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Here's a photo of my table with one record in it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hXoh.jpg)

But I've also tried the URL in place of the absolute path: https://memoriaelinguagrumentina/dictionaryAudio/a1.com

In either case, the path displays as text.

Any suggestions on how to get the audio to display on my webpage as something clickable?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72508063/edit) to show an example of one of the values of the `audio` column. Absolute paths sometimes need to be manipulated before they can be used in a URL, if they extend above the web server's document root.

Answer (score 1):

You have to output the `$row["audio"]` as a HTML a tag, but the absolute path is not always the path the file is accessible from outside.

The PHP code should look like something like this:

```
echo "id: ".$row["id"]." - Name: ".$row["word"]." <a href='".$row["audio"]."'>Click here to play audio</a><br>";
```

But for example if your audio file's path is `/var/www/website/files/01.mp3` this isn't the path that can be used as a http link. You should convert it to a useable URL. If in the above example, your domain is `website.com` and your document root on the server is the `/var/www/website` you should do something like this:

```
func FilePathToURL($fp) {
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http";
    return $protocol."://website.com".substr($fp, strlen("/var/www/website"));
}
```

And use this function to echo the correct link like:

```
echo "<a href='".FilePathToURL($row['audio'])."'>Click here</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to change it so the echo that you output to the page is wrapped in an anchor tag something like this. You'll need to add in the href where it is going to be going based on your data tho.

```
echo "<a href=''>" . "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["word"]. " " . $row["audio"] . "</a>" . "<br>";
```

Comment: I have tried that. My echo statement looked like this: `echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " adl: " . $row["adl"] . " audio: " . <a href="$row["audio"]">Listen</a> . </br>;` Though once insice the <a> tag, the PHP $row tag doesn't seem to get read the right way. In VS Code the $row in the tag is the color of most links and not the color of a PHP tag.

Comment: that is because you still need to separate out the variable, Try something like this:

echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " adl: " . $row["adl"] . " audio: " . "<a href='" . $row["audio"] . "'>Listen</a> . </br>";

Answer (score 0):

Since your `audio` values begin with "/public_html/...", you need to remove that leading string since presumably your web root already points there:

```
echo 'id: ' . $row['id'] . ' - Name: <a href="' . preg_replace('/^\/public_html/', '', $row['audio']) . '">' . $row['word'] . '</a><br>';
```

This should result in HTML that looks something like:

```
id: 1: - Name: <a href="/mlg/dictionaryAudio/a1.wav">word</a><br>
```